# Why is kivy changing the size of my widgets to the size of my screen when I click?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to make a class that makes a rectangle that you can click on the sides and drag to resize it. Only the left and down sides detect a click because the other two sides need the size to detect and as soon as someone clicks the widget sizes are immediately changed to the size of the screen. When you begin to drag from the bottom or left It works exactly how it's supposed to except for the fact that it has been magically resized. I suspect this is a problem with kivy and not my syntax but here's my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, ReferenceListProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.factory import Factory


class Root(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        FloatLayout.__init__(self)
        self.add_widget(SubWindow(pos=(100, 400), size=(200, 200), color=(1., .5, .5, 1.)))
        self.add_widget(SubWindow(pos=(0, 0), size=(100, 500), color=(.5, 0.0, 1., 1.)))

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
    return Root()


class SubWindow(Widget):
    x = NumericProperty(0)
    y = NumericProperty(0)
    tPosRel = ReferenceListProperty(x, y)
    bcolor = ListProperty()
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Widget.__init__(self)
        f = kwargs['color']
        self.size = kwargs['size']
        self.pos = kwargs['pos']
        self.bcolor = [f[0], f[1], f[2], f[3]]
        print(self.bcolor)
        self.draw()

    def draw(self, *largs):
        print("size[0]: " + str(self.size[0]))
        print("size[1]: " + str(self.size[1]))
        print("pos[0]: " + str(self.pos[0]))
        print("pos[1]: " + str(self.pos[1]))
        print(self)
        print('Drawing...')
        self.canvas.clear()
        with self.canvas:
            Color(self.bcolor[0], self.bcolor[1], self.bcolor[2], self.bcolor[3])
            Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        #print(self.size)
        print("Mouse X: " + str(touch.x))
        print("Mouse Y: " + str(touch.y))
        if touch.x > self.pos[0] and touch.x < self.pos[0] + self.size[0] and touch.y > self.pos[1] + self.size[1] and touch.y < self.pos[1] + self.size[1] + 10.0:
            self.side = 'up'
            print("up hit detect...")
            self.yInit = self.pos[1]
            #self.tPosRel = touch - self.pos
            touch.grab(self)

        if touch.x > self.pos[0] + self.size[0] and touch.x < self.pos[0] + self.size[0] + 10.0 and touch.y > self.pos[1] and touch.y < self.pos[1] + self.size[1]:
            self.side = 'right'
            print("right hit detect...")
            self.xInit = self.pos[0]
            touch.grab(self)

        if touch.x > self.pos[0] and touch.x < self.pos[0] + self.size[0] and touch.y > self.pos[1] - 10 and touch.y < self.pos[1]:
            self.side = 'down'
            print("down hit detect...")
            self.yInit = self.pos[1]
            touch.grab(self)

        if touch.x > self.pos[0] - 10 and touch.x < self.pos[0] and touch.y > self.pos[1] and touch.y < self.pos[1] + self.size[1]:
            self.side = 'left'
            print("left hit detect...")
            print(self.size)
            self.xInit = self.pos[0]
            touch.grab(self)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current is self:
            self.drag(touch)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current is self:
            touch.ungrab(self)

    def drag(self, touch):
        def up():
            self.size[1] = touch.y - self.pos[1]
            self.draw()

        def right():
            self.size[0] = touch.x - self.pos[0]
            self.draw()

        def down():
            self.size[1] += self.yInit - touch.y
            self.pos[1] = touch.y
            self.draw()

        def left():
            print("New Size: " + str(self.wInit + self.xInit - touch.x))
            print("touch.x: " + str(touch.x))
            print("self.xInit: ", str(self.xInit))
            print("self.wInit: ", str(self.wInit))
            self.size[0] += self.xInit - touch.x
            self.pos[0] = touch.x
            self.draw()

        def window():
            self.pos += touch - self.tPosRel


        c = {'up': up, 'right': right, 'down': down, 'left': left, 'window': window}
        c[self.side]()


Factory.register('SubWindow', SubWindow)
TestApp().run()
```

By the way I'm using python 3.6 with kivy 1.10.0 on windows 10. I have kivy.deps.glew instead of kivy.deps.angle despite my software being to date due to the fact some of the supporting libraries have not been updated for it yet.

Comment: Not sure if this is the full answer, but I think you need to add 
        `self.size_hint = (None, None)` to your `SubWindow.__init__()` method. Otherwise, your references to `self.size` will be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks man that fixed it